# Print multiple copies of report with WHERE clause and without opening Preview

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

In Datasheet view I created unbounded `txtPrintMe` field with doubleclick event on it. (because buttons are not allowed in Datasheet view).
I added VBA to print report.

```
Private Sub txtPrintMe_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptOrder", acViewNormal, , "id = " & Me.txtOrderID
    DoCmd.PrintOut , , , , , 2
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptOrder"
End Sub
```

When I execute this I get printed 1 copy of my report **AND also underlying Form view where my `txtPrintMe` is located**. When I remove PrintOut I get single copy printed out without any issues.

What I want to do: I simply need to print 2 copies of my report without opening Preview mode. I need to do this as efficient (fast printing) as I can.

Probably I want to merge all copies in single document and only then to send it to the printer as single file. But this is optional.

Comment: Repeat the OpenReport line. To print as single file export to two PDFs then merge the PDFs. Not simple code. Or build the report with everything duplicated (be thankful for 'copy/paste') and use a page break code.

Comment: Tnx. Repeating OpenReport really works! :D :D So stupid... LOL :D But still interested in some more nice approach.

Comment: Why is Preview an issue?

Comment: If you need to print 100+ Orders in few minutes - would you open Preview for every document? It is Time & Click wasting. No need to looks at Preview every time. Just print it out and that's it! Go to next operation. To export PDF or send to email I have other tools.

Comment: The code opens and prints and closes report. User will see it but why would that be an issue? They can't do anything else until the print operation completes. I have automated the output of any number of reports at one time, often having to open in PrintPreview before sending to printer (or to PDF).

Comment: In my case I don't need to open it. Every unnecessary operation takes time for the user.

Comment: Options discussed are all I am aware of.